# Trying to set a coordinate to be the origin point adds another random point instead of pushing it to the front

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a program for the traveling salesman problem that uses a nearest neighbor method. I am using Django for this project. The problem is, when I try to set one of the coordinate objects to the front of the calculation, it adds another different point to be the origin. Is there anything obviously wrong with my program?

#calcRoute.py

```
from django.db import models
from .models import Coordinate, SortedPoint
import math

class Point:
  def __init__(self, longitude, latitude, isPassed, isOrigin):
    self.longitude = longitude
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.isPassed = isPassed
    self.isOrigin = isOrigin

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2): # haversine formula to caluclate distance between points on a globe
    # convert degrees to radians
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(math.radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])

    # calculate distance
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a))
    r = 6378  # radius of earth in kilometers
    return c * r

def nearest_neighbor(points, origin): # return the nearest neighbor
  nearestNeighbor = None
  nearestDistance = float('inf')
  
  for point in points:
    # skip the origin point
    if point == origin:
      continue
      
    distance = haversine(origin.longitude, origin.latitude, point.longitude, point.latitude)
    
    if distance < nearestDistance:
      nearestNeighbor = point
      nearestDistance = distance
      
  return nearestNeighbor

def save_points(points): # save points to db
  for point in points:
    sorted_point = SortedPoint(longitude=point.longitude, latitude=point.latitude, isPassed=point.isPassed)
    sorted_point.save()

def calc_route():
  SortedPoint.objects.all().delete()
  # load coordinates from db
  coordinates = Coordinate.objects.all()
 
  points = [Point(coordinate.longitude, coordinate.latitude, False, coordinate.isOrigin) for coordinate in coordinates]
  origin = points[0]
  for i in range(len(points)):
    if points[i].isOrigin is True:
      origin = points[i]
  ending = origin
  passedPoints = [origin]
  currentPoint = origin
  points.remove(origin)

  while len(points) > 0:
    nearestNeighbor = nearest_neighbor(points, currentPoint)
    passedPoints.append(nearestNeighbor)
    points.remove(nearestNeighbor)
    currentPoint = nearestNeighbor

  # append origen to the list of passed points
  passedPoints.append(ending)
  save_points(passedPoints) #save
```

#views.py

```
def set_origin(request, id):
    point = SortedPoint.objects.get(id=id)
    point.isOrigin = True
    return redirect('editRoute')

@login_required(login_url='administration')
def update_coords(request):
    Coordinate.objects.all().delete()
    sorted_points = SortedPoint.objects.all()
    for sorted_point in sorted_points:
        coord = Coordinate(latitude=sorted_point.latitude, longitude=sorted_point.longitude, routeName=sorted_point.routeName, isPassed=sorted_point.isPassed, isOrigin=sorted_point.isOrigin)
        coord.save()
    
    calc_route()
    return redirect('editRoute')
```

#models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.


class Coordinate(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    routeName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='abc')
    isPassed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isOrigin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class SortedPoint(models.Model):
  longitude = models.FloatField()
  latitude = models.FloatField()
  routeName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='abc')
  isPassed = models.BooleanField()
  isOrigin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

#urls.py (within urlpatterns[])

```
path('edit-route/set_origin/<int:id>/', views.set_origin, name='set_origin'),
    path('edit-route/update_coords/', views.update_coords, name='update_coords'),
```

I have tried multiple different ways of setting it as the origin, tried different points to be the origin, and asked some friends. None of it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Questions of the form "why doesn't my code work?" are out of scope for this site.  You need to ask a question that involves a single programming concept or asks about a particular issue with your code or points to a problem involving just a few lines of code.  I would suggest that you run your code in a debugger, watch what it does line by line, look at the values in the variables used by the code, and reason out why it doesn't work as you intend. This is how programmers work.  We don't ask others for help when our code isn't acting as we expect.

Comment: i have already done that. it adds the isOrigin tag to the object but for some reason it does not get recognized in the for loop portion of the calcRoute.py file. Sorry if the title wasn't as specific

Comment: update: forgot to put in 'point.save()'. fml

Comment: Please check out what it means to supply a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and consider supplying one instead of what you've supplied so far.  Some questions/suggestion towards this idea: 1) does your problem really have anything to do with django? If not, isolating an example that doesn't use it is preferred. 2) what do you mean by "set one of the coordinate objects to the front of the calculation"?  3) How do you see that "it adds another different point to be the origin"?  A good MRE would likely make the answers to these question more obvious.